# Inertia Link not redirecting on click (this.resolveComponent is not a function)

Tags: django, vuejs3, inertiajs

I'm trying to get Django, Inertia and Vue running.

I followed this doc (including the referred ones inside that): https://pypi.org/project/inertia-django/

While it works basically (the Vue pages/components render, pages load), I can't use the `<Link>` component. It renders and shows the correct destination on hovering, but when you click on it, the console shows `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.resolveComponent is not a function` and it's not redirecting.
Although it's not changing the page, I can see the corresponding get request in the django server console.

The router.visit() function works fine.

[image]

**main.html**

```
{% load django_vite %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    {% vite_hmr_client %}
    {% vite_asset 'js/main.js' %}
    <title>Django-mysite</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>
<body>
{% block inertia %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
import 'vite/modulepreload-polyfill'
import {createApp, h} from 'vue';
import {createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/vue3';


const pages = import.meta.glob('./pages/**/*.vue');
createInertiaApp({
    resolve: async name => {
        return (await pages[`./pages/${name}.vue`]()).default
    },
    setup({el, App, props, plugin}) {
        const app = createApp({render: () => h(App, props)})
        app.use(plugin)
        app.mount(el)
    },
})
```

**vite.config.js**

```
const { resolve } = require('path');
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

module.exports = {
  plugins: [vue()],
  root: resolve('./static/src'),
  base: '/static/',
  server: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3000,
    open: false,
    watch: {
      usePolling: true,
      disableGlobbing: false,
    },
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.json', ".vue"],
  },
  build: {
    outDir: resolve('./static/dist'),
    assetsDir: '',
    manifest: true,
    emptyOutDir: true,
    target: 'es2015',
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        main: resolve('./static/src/js/main.js'),
      },
      output: {
        chunkFileNames: undefined,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "js",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3": "^0.6.0",
    "@inertiajs/vue3": "^1.0.1",
    "vue": "^3.2.45"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.0.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.6",
    "vite": "^4.1.0"
  }
}
```

**the component that renders the link**

```
<template>
    <Link :href="href"
          :class="[$page.component === component ? 'bg-indigo-800 text-white' : 'text-indigo-100 hover:bg-indigo-600', 'group flex gap-2 items-center px-2 py-2 text-sm font-medium rounded-md']">
        <i :class="icon"></i>
        <slot></slot>
    </Link>
</template>

<script setup>
import { Link } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';

let name = "SidebarLink";

defineProps({
    href: String,
    icon: String,
    component: String,
});

</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

**settings.py**

```
"""
Django settings for webinterface2 project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.1.6.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/
"""
import os
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-+d3n=o3f&4el6mmh0_-gbk$ktk^2*o_(x@k*i8hx*ipkf(5*my'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    "inertia",
    "django_vite",
    "app"
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    "inertia.middleware.InertiaMiddleware"
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'webinterface2.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'webinterface2.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")

# INERTIA_LAYOUT =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "app", "templates", "base.html")
INERTIA_LAYOUT = "main.html"
DJANGO_VITE_ASSETS_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static", "dist")
DJANGO_VITE_DEV_MODE = DEBUG

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "collectedstatic")
STATICFILES_DIRS = [DJANGO_VITE_ASSETS_PATH]

CSRF_HEADER_NAME = 'HTTP_X_XSRF_TOKEN'
CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = 'XSRF-TOKEN'
```

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that unfortunately my IDE imported the wrong module.
It seems that `{ Link }` is available in both of them and because of that you don't get an error like module not found.

```
<template>
    <Link :href="href"
          :class="[$page.component === component ? 'bg-indigo-800 text-white' : 'text-indigo-100 hover:bg-indigo-600', 'group flex gap-2 items-center px-2 py-2 text-sm font-medium rounded-md']">
        <i :class="icon"></i>
        <slot></slot>
    </Link>
</template>

<script setup>
import { Link } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3'; // <-- wrong import
import { Link } from "@inertiajs/vue3"; // <-- correct

let name = "SidebarLink";

defineProps({
    href: String,
    icon: String,
    component: String,
});

</script>
```